# Error when calling a an API from JavaScript but not from Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, watson

I'm writing a web app in express and one of the resources is exposed through an API with an endpoint on 'api/tone'. The API is just a wrapper for one of Watson's services, but I don't call them directly so as not to do all the authentication and payload building on the front-end. The API itself is working just fine because when I try to reach it with POSTMAN, it responds correctly.

## **POSTMAN request info:**

> **POST**: localhost:3000/api/tone
>
> **Headers**: "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>
> **Body**: "text": "The king is a lovely chap. He makes me feel like I'm back at home with my family."

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGrmV.png)

This request works exactly as intended.

*The app is just a prototype showcasing other functionalities, so it doesn't use any sort of authentication.*

## The Javascript Request

The problem comes when I try to call the API from my front-end.

```js
function sendRequest(text) {
    var payloadToWatson = {};
    payloadToWatson.text = text;

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", messageEndpoint, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(payloadToWatson));
}
```

Here I get a POST bad request error. When I log the error on the backend, this comes off:

> {"code":400,"sub_code":"C00007","error":"No text given","x-global-transaction-id":"ffea405d5a5a00dd017a0dbb"}

I'm 99% sure the problem is in the front-end API caller, otherwise, POSTMAN requests wouldn't work, but I still can't find how to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not sending the same thing. With postman you are not sending json.

Just send `text` without stringifying :

```
xhttp.send({text: text});
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally made it work. And by I, I mean is used POSTMAN *code* tool. Instead of sending the data to be analyzed as a JS object or a stringified JSON:

```
   var payloadToWatson = {};
   payloadToWatson.text = text;
   ...
   xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(payloadToWatson));
```

I had to do was create a string using equal signs between the parameters and the values:

```
   var data = "text=" + text;
   xhttp.send(data);
```

Works perfectly now.